# Arduino Multi Thread

Tags: multithreading

I Am working with arduino mega 2560....
Here I want to toggle two led simultaneously using threading.....
but there is problem that it is running one by one...
here is the code...
it would b your pleasure...

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Thread.h>
#include <ThreadController.h>

Thread Led1=Thread();
Thread Led2=Thread();
ThreadController controll=ThreadController();
void Led1run()
{
  Serial.println("Led1");
  Led2.run();
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
  }
 void Led2run()
{
  Serial.println("Led2");
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(53,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(53,LOW);
     delay(1000);
  }
}
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Led1.onRun(Led1run);
  Led2.onRun(Led2run);
  controll.add(&Led1);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(53,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    Serial.println("loop");
    Led1.run();
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the link to the Thread library?